# How to create a new formula for a fractal-type image?

Tags: algorithms, fractals

(If this is the wrong place to ask, then PLEASE tell me where to take the question instead of chewing me out over this.)

I have been learning how to write out SVG by hand, and in the process made a pattern that can be replicated inside and outside itself to produce a fractal or fractal-like image. What I'm wanting to know is how to write a formula to generate it procedurally, instead of having to calculate by hand all the time.

Going in or out, the image has square dimensions; for in, the number has to be divisible by 6 and 3; for out, the number needs to be divisible by 6 and 3 again, but also produce a number no smaller than 3 for whole real numbers once divided.

The following is a properly formatted (to my knowledge) HTML document with 3 inline SVG segments that can be saved and looked at. If there's any way to post the saved document, that would be much appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <style>
      path {fill:none; stroke:black; stroke-width:1 }
      p {text-align:center }
    </style>
    <title>
      Test
    </title>
   </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      <svg width="30" height="30">
        <path d="M 15,0 L 30,15 L 15,30 L 0,15 Z"/>
        <path d="M 15,0 L 25,15 L 15,30 L 5,15 Z"/>
        <path d="M 15,0 L 20,15 L 15,30 L 10,15 Z"/>
        <path d="M 15,5 L 30,15 L 15,25 L 0,15 Z"/>
        <path d="M 15,5 L 25,15 L 15,25 L 5,15 Z"/>
        <path d="M 15,5 L 20,15 L 15,25 L 10,15 Z"/>
        <path d="M 15,10 L 30,15 L 15,20 L 0,15 Z"/>
        <path d="M 15,10 L 25,15 L 15,20 L 5,15 Z"/>
        <path d="M 15,10 L 20,15 L 15,20 L 10,15 Z"/>
      </svg>
    </p>
    <p>
      <svg width="90" height="90">
        <path d="M 45,0 L 90,45 L 45,90 L 0,45 Z"/>
        <path d="M 45,0 L 75,45 L 45,90 L 15,45 Z"/
        <path d="M 45,0 L 60,45 L 45,90 L 30,45 Z"/>
        <path d="M 45,15 L 90,45 L 45,75 L 0,45 Z"/>
        <path d="M 45,15 L 75,45 L 45,75 L 15,45 Z"/>
        <path d="M 45,15 L 60,45 L 45,75 L 30,45 Z"/>
        <path d="M 45,30 L 90,45 L 45,60 L 0,45 Z"/>
        <path d="M 45,30 L 75,45 L 45,60 L 15,45 Z"/>
        <path d="M 45,30 L 60,45 L 45,60 L 30,45 Z"/>
        <path d="M 45,30 L 55,45 L 45,60 L 35,45 Z"/>
        <path d="M 45,30 L 50,45 L 45,60 L 40,45 Z"/>
        <path d="M 45,35 L 60,45 L 45,55 L 30,45 Z"/>
        <path d="M 45,35 L 55,45 L 45,55 L 35,45 Z"/>
        <path d="M 45,35 L 50,45 L 45,55 L 40,45 Z"/>
        <path d="M 45,40 L 60,45 L 45,50 L 30,45 Z"/>
        <path d="M 45,40 L 55,45 L 45,50 L 35,45 Z"/>
        <path d="M 45,40 L 50,45 L 45,50 L 40,45 Z"/>
      </svg>
    </p>
    <p>
      <svg width="270" height="270">
        <path d="M 135,0 L 270,135 L 135,270 L 0,135 Z"/>
        <path d="M 135,0 L 225,135 L 135,270 L 45,135 Z"/>
        <path d="M 135,0 L 180,135 L 135,270 L 90,135 Z"/>
        <path d="M 135,45 L 270,135 L 135, 225 L 0,135 Z"/>
        <path d="M 135,45 L 225,135 L 135,225 L 45,135 Z"/>
        <path d="M 135,45 L 180,135 L 135,225 L 90,135 Z"/>
        <path d="M 135,90 L 270,135 L 135,180 L 0,135 Z"/>
        <path d="M 135,90 L 225,135 L 135,180 L 45,135 Z"/>
        <path d="M 135,90 L 180,135 L 135,180 L 90,135 Z"/>
        <path d="M 135,90 L 165,135 L 135,180 L 105,135 Z"/>
        <path d="M 135,90 L 150,135 L 135,180 L 120,135 Z"/>
        <path d="M 135,105 L 180,135 L 135,165 L 90,135 Z"/>
        <path d="M 135,105 L 165,135 L 135,165 L 105,135 Z"/>
        <path d="M 135,105 L 150,135 L 135,165 L 120,135 Z"/>
        <path d="M 135,120 L 180,135 L 135,150 L 90,135 Z"/>
        <path d="M 135,120 L 165,135 L 135,150 L 105,135 Z"/>
        <path d="M 135,120 L 150,135 L 135,150 L 120,135 Z"/>
        <path d="M 135,120 L 145,135 L 135,150 L 125,135 Z"/>
        <path d="M 135,120 L 140,135 L 135,150 L 130,135 Z"/>
        <path d="M 135,125 L 150,135 L 135,145 L 120,135 Z"/>
        <path d="M 135,125 L 145,135 L 135,145 L 125,135 Z"/>
        <path d="M 135,125 L 140,135 L 135,145 L 130,135 Z"/>
        <path d="M 135,130 L 150,135 L 135,140 L 120,135 Z"/>
        <path d="M 135,130 L 145,135 L 135,140 L 125,135 Z"/>
        <path d="M 135,130 L 140,135 L 135,140 L 130,135 Z"/>
      </svg>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Felix

Comment: I created a JSbin to display your SVG's: (http://jsbin.com/vumihohove/edit?html,output)